# Why is an optional in Swift giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

I have the following code:

```
// Get the matches
var recipieMatches = queryResults[MATCHES_INDEX] as Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>
// Set some global vars
var numberOfRecipiesToDisplay: Int = recipieMatches.count

for i in 0...(numberOfRecipiesToDisplay - 1)
{
    var time:  Int? = ((recipieMatches[i])["totalTimeInSeconds"]) as Int? // THIS LINE
}
```

I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the line in the for loop.

**My Question**: How is this possible? I know `recipieMatches[i]` is a value since the for loop iterates over the count of the array.

Comment: What type of variable is `numberOfRecipiesToDisplay`? What is `numberOfRecipiesToDisplay.keys.`?

Comment: Sorry about that, just fixed it up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`as` will crash if the value you're extracting isn't the correct type - in this case if it isn't an `Int?`

Instead, use optional casting - `as?`. If the value isn't an `Int?` then the optional will be `nil`.

Comment: @RichieEpiscopo If the answer helped you, please click the check box next to my answer to mark it as accepted. This will stop other people from seeing the question when they search for unanswered questions.